# Public folder isn't working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to serve an image to my meteor app so I put the image in the public folder, but the image doesn't appears in the app (it shows only a broken image). But when I put the image in the root folder it works perfectly.

In other question related with this kind of problem I was that I should look in side the app_root/.meteor/build/static/, but in my app I don't have any static folder inside the build folder

What could be the problem?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it is exceedingly hard to tell you what the issue is.

Comment: I think that the problem isn't related with some code, because the image appears when I put him outside the public folder. In other question related with this kind of problem I was that I should look in side the app_root/.meteor/build/static/, but in my app I don't have any static folder inside the build folder.

Comment: Are you talking about development or your app is bundled for production?

Comment: I'm talking about in development mode

Comment: what is the URL you are using in your HTML to show the image?

Comment: Is this one: <img src="public/logo.png" id="logo">

Comment: The url is correct, right?

Comment: The url should be `/logo.png`. Stuff in `/public` is mapped to `/`.

Comment: Regarding the static folder, when Meteor builds an app it restructures it, all 'static' files, such as the ones in `/public` are put in this static folder. You can see what the structure of the app would be by looking inside a bundle with created with `meteor bundle`. In production you wont have a public folder anymore this is why you see static instead.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but I have another problem. In some routes, for example when I submit some data to the server, the image disappears and the console prints this: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/articles/logo.png".

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended you use `./public` directory for serving static assets.

Given the following directory structure:

```
- server
- client
- public
  - css
    - bootstrap.css
  - images
  - js
```

You could serve the static assets by dropping 'public' from linked documents.

`<link href='/css/bootstrap.css'>`

> Files in /public are served to the client as-is. Use this to store
>   assets such as images. For example, if you have an image located at
>   /public/background.png, you can include it in your HTML with  or in your CSS with background-image:
>   url(/background.png). Note that /public is not part of the image URL.

[Official Meteor Docs - File Structure](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure)

Comment: _<link href='/css/bootstrap.css'>_
If you are linking something from static folder the href should start with a '/'

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me either until I stumbled upon the reason. If you are serving a page that is on the root ('/'), any image like this will work as long as `myImage.jpg` is located in the `public` directory:

```
<img src="myImage.jpg"/>
```

It will work as long as your pages are on the root route. However, if you are serving a route like `/pages/HJ4HIW87JURE6JU8`, if you use the same image tag, it will not find the image in `public`. In order to make this work, you need to add a `/` to your image tag to tell it to start from the root:

```
<img src="/myImage.jpg"/>
```

Using the root slash, you can serve images from public from anywhere in your route structure.